# Microsoft equivalent of Dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver

What is the `Microsoft` equivalent of `Adobe Dreamweaver`?

ie. Drag and drop visual editor for web pages

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft FrontPage, I believe, would be the closest equivalent of Dreamweaver. It is a What You See Is What You Get (WYSIWYG) type editor similar to Dreamweaver.

see the description [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage)

Comment: or Visual Studio. But that option isn't a WYSIWYG IDE like Dreamweaver.